# Prometheus find average of minimum at each point over time

Tags: prometheus, promql

we have multiple "up"-metrics from health checks of multiple services in prometheus. Binary values 0 is down, 1 is up .
Within prometheus we would like to calculate the uptime of each service (aggregation in prometheus). A service is up, if all its health checks are up, the association to services is stored as label in prometheus, thats easy, but now we want to calculate the average over the time of this.

How can we build the average over time from the minimum at every point in time?
I think we need some `min` function that uses and returns a range vector. But `min_over_time` is having a range vector as input, but returns a instant vector, but we need it more as `min_of_each_time`

If you need any further infos, i can also provide an example, but maybe its easy for somebody?!

BR
Marius

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, after some chats with colleagues, i found a solution.
While scraping we aggregate the health_checks by service_id. This is done via prometheus recording/aggregation rules. Then later on we can use the avg_over_time function to calculate the availability.

```
  #Aggregate health check availability per service
  - record: service_health_status_aggregated
    expr:  min(consul_health_status) by (serviceName, serviceId, env, dc)
```